# what are "key points" [opencv context] and what do FAST, GetStarKeypoints etc do?

Tags: opencv

So i was surfing the web look for eye corner detection techniques to aid me in my project of gaze estimation, here : [eye corner tracking - best algo](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/messages/74054?threaded=1&m=e&var=1&tidx=1) and there this page was linked : [Feature Detection - opencv documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/feature_detection.html)

So i got to thinking maybe this would be useful for me in my eye corner detection. But then i clicked on that documentation page and i didn't understand anything

I thought i might google the terms first, see what they mean, get an idea then as to what is happening in those algorithms - like for eg, in GetStarKeypoints , it says it retrieves keypoints - which i googled - and nothing came up about key-points. I gathered from a post here what they might be - points to classify object based on distinct features. But i'm really i'm not clear.
Everywhere i see either code or some use of the algorithms' OpenCV functions, no examples of before and after.

Anyways, the bottom line is, I want to know if they can any significant way be useful to me for my journey complete gaze estimation for my project? 
I've gotten the pupil, I've gotten the eye-corners roughly using thresholding and Sobel and CornerHarris etc.

Answer (score 0):

The keywords which you are talking about, represent recent developments in image processing area and hence net is nut abuzz with explainations of them. If you really wish to go in depth you will have go through research papers. For stardetector here is the [link](http://www.springerlink.com/content/ngx06074r126x362/).

Comment: thanks, that's ok
but i was hoping for some short introduction as to what they do and if they can help me in my project. Probably people who have used them would be able to answer that